# <html:rewrite page="" > tag equivalent in Struts 2

Tags: jsp, url, url-rewriting, struts2, struts1

What is equivalent in Struts2 for `<html:rewrite>` tag?

```
<html:rewrite page="/MyAction.action">
```

Comment: `<s:url />` . What do you need, exactly ?

Comment: I need to change the page into the site with the base uri http://localhost:8081/myapp/control/ .  For example I tried to change on click on a button: http://localhost:8081/myapp/control/myHomeAction.action to http://localhost:8081/myapp/control/myNextPageAction.action

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `url` tag to build the url, this is equivalent of html rewrite tag.

```jsp
<s:url var="myUrl" action="MyAction"/>
```

---

But if you need rewrite the url, then you can use a path

```jsp
<s:url var="myUrl" value="/MyAction.action"/>
```

---

You can output the value with `<s:property value="%{#myUrl}"/>` or `${myUrl}` in the JSP where possible.

You can read more about [url tag](http://struts.apache.org/docs/url.html) on the Struts docs site.